# Проверка ряда значений через empty

Tags: php

Есть задача: нужно проверить на предмет наличия значений в ряде переменных. Есть ли какой-то "человеческий" способ или каждую нужно перебирать через `empty`(или `isset`) ?

Есть конструкция вида:

```
    <?if(!empty($cPhone)||!empty($cUrl)||!empty($cDirectionLink['value'])||!empty($cLocation['value']['address'])):?>
<?echo 1;?>
<?else:?>
<?echo 0;?>
<?endif;?>
```

Comment: достаточно писать `if ($cPhone || cUrl)` и т.д.... емнип

Comment: для _т.д_ придется `@` ставить, ибо undefined index появиться может.

Comment: на всяк случай `<?echo` можно заменить на `<?=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом, человеческие способы уже давно придуманы и давно описаны в паттернах. К сожалению, нет такого паттерна, как Validator, это скорее всего набор определенных паттернов для использования в той или иной ситуации. Я рекомендую Вам прочитать про основные паттерны написания кода.

**Проблема вашего кода:**

1. Большой размер блока управляющей конструкции
2. Высокая связанность с функцией empty и невозможность ее заменить быстро во всех местах, где осуществляется подобная проверка.

Я приведу Вам простой пример класса, который решает подобные проблемы. В него конечно много что еще можно добавить, но в целом смысл остается.

Будем считать, что нам необходим класс, в который по сути можно добавить необходимые данные и одной функцией их проверить (чтобы не завязываться на указанную функцию). Назовем его Validator, будем добавлять данные методом add, а их валидацию производить методом validate.

Например, в вашем случае, было бы удобно воспользоваться чем-то следующим:

```
class Validator {

    protected $data;

    public function add($var) {
         $this->data[] = $var;

         return $this;
    }

    public function validate() : bool {

         $result = true;         

         foreach ($data as $item) {
              if (empty($item)) { 
                  $result = false;
              }
         }

         return $result;
    }

}


$validator = new Validator();
$result = $validator->add($cPhone)
                    ->add($cUrl)
                    ->add($cDirectionLink['value'])
                    ->add($cLocation['value']['address'])
                    ->validate();

echo ($result) ? 1 : 0;
```

**Вариантов реализации много**, можно например заменить валидатор описанный в классе на анонимную функцию и передавать функцию валидации, это правда подходит в определенных случаях:

```
class Validator {

    protected $data;

    public function add($var) {
         $this->data[] = $var;

         return $this;
    }

    public function validate(callable $call) : bool {

         $result = true;         

         foreach ($this->data as $item) {
              if ($call($item)) { 
                  $result = false;
              }
         }

         return $result;
    }

}


$validator = new Validator();
$result = $validator->add(0)
                    ->validate(function ($a) { return empty($a); });

echo ($result) ? 1 : 0;
```

**Работает на PHP 7.**

**Дополнение от 08.04.2017:**

Если вы имеете ввиду разом проверить - это передать в функцию сколько угодно аргументов, то разом проверить можно и для этого достаточно написать свою функцию с переменным числом аргументов, такие функции называются **вариативными**:

```
function checkEmpty()
{
  $num = func_num_args();
  $args = func_get_args();

  $result = true;   

  for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
  {
      if (empty($args[$i])) {
           $result = false;  
      }
  }

  return $result;
}

$r = 1;
$b = 1;
$n = 1;

$result = checkEmpty($r,$b,$n);

echo ($result) ? 1 : 0;
```

Такое решение не всегда стоит применять, отсутствие какого-то либо контроля типов и количества переменных может привести к серьезным ошибкам в вашем коде.

Comment: Ответ хорош. Но сущность остаётся также. Разом не получается проверить. Лишь через методы. А это тоже самое по самой логике

Comment: @Platon дополнил ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код более безопасен, т.к. когда обращаются к функции `empty`, она проверяет на isset и на empty.

Есть ещё вариант опустить обращение к функции `empty` и использовать условие:

```
<?if($cPhone || $cUrl || $cDirectionLink['value'] || $cLocation['value']['address']):?>
    <?echo 1;?>
<?else:?>
    <?echo 0;?>
<?endif;?>
```

Но тогда у вас могут появиться предупреждения что нет такой переменной или индекса массива с таким ключом, и в некоторых случаях код может не работать, всё зависит от настройки вывода ошибок [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php).